# Запросы PDO для абстрактного класса и его подклассов

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Всем привет,
В общем, мне необходимо динамически загружать сразу несколько запросов в одну строчку БД MySQL, я могу записать, но из этого выходит несколько строчек, на каждый подкласс, вот пример из кода, моего...

```
public function prepare($sql, $options = []) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        if(!empty($options)) {
            foreach ($options as $key => &$val) {
                $query->bindParam($key, $val);
} $query->execute
}
```

От подклассов идут запросы, и данные

Help...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: Чуток не то,
Мне надо забаиндить также параметры, которые не известны

Comment: "Мне надо забаиндить также параметры, которые не известны" - это вообще как? забаиндить то незнамо что?

Comment: ну когда bindparam получает ключи к примеру, неизвестные

Comment: Но вы тут и так биндите все параметры, которые пришли в массиве на входе. что именно вас в этом не устраивает ? Хотя в pdo это конечно совершенно не нужно, достаточно сделать $query->execute($options), он сам все параметры привяжет

Comment: Хай Майк, просто у меня несколько запросов приходит, то есть в БД получается несколько строк, а нужна только одна

Comment: В общем, мне надо собрать несколько запросов, и одним махом закинуть сразу все, в одну строку в БД

Comment: `public function prepare($sql, $options = NULL) {
        //$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        //if(!empty($options)) {
            //foreach ($options as $key => &$val) {
               // $query->bindParam($key, $val);
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);;
            $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->arrayOfQueries[] = $result;`

Comment: значит вы как то не так вызываете данный метод (например несколько раз) или используете не правильный SQL запрос. В вопросе не показано, как вы данный метод вызываете, а поэтому нельзя сказать что именно не так. По тому как этот метод написан он выполнит переданный ему sql-запрос ровно один раз и если это одиночный insert с ровно одним набором values вставит ровно одну строку

Comment: Хорошо, а как собрать все запросы в один array?